# Call Parent function from route this.props.children in React

Tags: reactjs

I have below layout and in this layout Route pages are being rendered.

```
 const Layout = () => {
     return (
         <main className="fadeIn animated">
               { this.props.children }
       </main>
    )
  }

return (
 <React.Fragment>
    <Layout callFunction={ () => console.log('callFunction') }/>

 {/*I will set the state using callFunction Function and then pass in modal*/}

    <Modals data={this.state}/>
 </React.Fragment>
)
```

The page that is being rendered inside the children using route is below

```
class Page extends React.Component {
    return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    ROUTE PAGE IS . I would like to call callFunction from here
      <button onClick={parent.callFunction}>CALL</button>
                </React.Fragment>
        )

}
```

I would like to call callFunction function of Layout Component from Children Page in reactjs

Comment: This code as it is is hard to work with. Where are those `return` statements ? Why is there JSX in Layout that is not used for anything ?

Comment: This is just  an example

Comment: The JSX in `Layout` is not used for anything, what is it ?. And what's the `return` statement below for ?

Comment: I said the Layout { this.props.children } is being rendered using Route

Comment: Alright, is the last bit of code supposed to be `Layout`'s children there ?

Comment: last bit of code is something that is replaced by Route in place of this.props.children

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you wish "Layout" to run the "loadLayout" function
if so, just let the Layout know what it's receiving

```
 const Layout = ({loadLayout}) => {
   loadLayout()
   return (
     <main className="fadeIn animated">
           { this.props.children }
   </main>
  )
}
```

I'm not sure this is what you meant, we need more info, who loads who

Comment: I still dont get it. who calls page? the second render belongs to.. who?

Comment: <Link to="/"><i className="zmdi zmdi-apps"/>Page </Link>
On clicking this it open Page inside  { this.props.children }

Comment: you have then: Link -> Page -> WHO_IS_HERE -> Layout